# visualize a triangulation generated by CGAL

Tags: visualization, cgal, triangulation

I am new to CGAL. I generated a triangulated surface from a set of points, how can i visualize it in order to make sense? 
The documentation of CGAL has nothing clear about visualization.
From searching the Internet I found this piece of code https://www-sop.inria.fr/geometrica/courses/slides/triangulations-2D.pdf:

```
void gl_draw_voronoi_edges() {
::glBegin(GL_LINES);
Edge_iterator hEdge;
for (hEdge = edges_begin(); hEdge != edges_end(); hEdge++)
{
CGAL::Object object = dual(hEdge);
Segment segment;
Ray ray;
Point source, target;
if(CGAL::assign(segment,object))
{
source = segment.source();
target = segment.target();
}
else if(CGAL::assign(ray,object))
{
source = ray.source();
target = ray.point(1);
}
::glVertex2f(source.x(),source.y());
::glVertex2f(target.x(),target.y());
}
::glEnd(); }
```

but I don't how to use it?

Comment: If you just want to visualize, you can use the demo located in the directory `demo/Triangulation_2` of a CGAL release. If you are on windows there is a precompiled demo available [here](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.8/delaunay_triangulation_2.zip) with required dlls [here](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.8/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip)

Comment: yes, I want to visualize my own data. Aren't demos for a shipped example of the CGAL package? if not how can I use them for my own data?

Answer (score 2):

To know everything about visualization, see http://doc.cgal.org/latest/GraphicsView/index.html#Chapter_CGAL_and_the_Qt_Graphics_View_Framework

yes, demos are shipped with CGAL, as already answered above: "you can use the demo located in the directory demo/Triangulation_2 of a CGAL release."